# Add global interceptor and header to all axios clients after created?

Tags: axios

I have created multiple axios clients to access different apis.

After user login, I want to add a header holding the auth token, and a response interceptor to check if the token expired error is returned.

```js
export const userClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'url/to/account'
});
export const projectClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'url/to/projects'
});
...
```

Do I have to repeat

```
userClient.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${access_token}`;
```

and

```
userClient.interceptors.response.use(...) // check token expired response
```

for all clients?

Or is there any way to do this once and apply to all clients?